# Access the memory of a auto variable inside a block from outside the block?

Tags: c, variables, memory-management, scope

In my mind, the auto variable in block would be deallocated after jumping to outer scope. Then I wrote a program to test this and to my surprise, it ran ok. It even ran multiple times.

The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *a = 0;

    {   
        int b = 2;
        a = &b; 
    }   

    printf("%d\n", *a);
    return 0;
}
```

the print result is 2, how does this happen?

Comment: That memory is still there, it just will be clobbered by the next function call or block scope.  Its like reading from memory after free'ing a heap allocated block.  You can't count on it working, but sometimes it does.

Comment: Simple, you were lucky. The memory is marked as "free" but is not "freed" because there is no need to do so unless someone else asks for it.

Comment: just like the guy live up floor gives you an computer, even that guy moved out, you still have the computer in your home

Comment: In certain environments this would have resulted in an error, detecting an invalid memory access;

Answer (score 2):

As per ANSI standard, any reference of the automatic variable 'b' out side of the block is invalid. It depends on compiler, how they push and pop local variables on stack frame. Probably your compiler is popping all locals when it exits from outer most block.

You will also be able to read the address even if it is not on stack. This address may get modified by some other variable if the stack further grows. In this case you will not be able to read the same data again.

Comment: My compiler is gcc 4.4.7. Do you mean that if compiler pop the auto variables after the inner block end, the previous memory would be overriden by new auto variables? for example if I add the statement after the block: int c = 3, then it would print: 3 other than 2?

Comment: yes, but it might be a case of popping all the local variables when it exits from outer most block. you can write a small program to know how it is pushing and popping local variables?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how compiler implements it? As per standards you can not use any local data type out side the block of its delaration.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of Automatic variables can be classified into these categories:

1. Global scope
2. Function scope
3. Block scope

Depending on where it is declared, it can have different "visibility".

In your code, variable "b" will be visible inside its scope only. It can have its memory allocated and can be used inside that scope. When outside, that memory is no longer associated with variable "b".

However, that does not mean it is freed. If you declare another variable or block, it may use the same memory location.

You can add few prints and check which memory is being referenced. That will give you better understanding.